# mysql selecting only business hours

Tags: php, mysql

I built an application where user posts a ticket then moderator rejects it or hands it to admin then admin approves or rejects.
In every process moderator and admin has 24 hours.
When user posts the ticket on weekend or after 17:00 on Friday I want it to it posts like on Monday at 09:00 (Because working hours 09:00 - 17:00).

```
SELECT step_one, offers.offer_department_in_charge as department, 
       offers.offer_id as id, COALESCE(cronjobmailsid.offer_id, 0) as cron_id 
FROM offers INNER JOIN status ON offers.offer_id=status.offer_id 
            LEFT JOIN cronjobmailsid on offers.offer_id = cronjobmailsid.offer_id 
WHERE status.status_id IN(SELECT MAX(status.status_id) 
                          FROM status 
                          GROUP BY status.offer_id) 
      AND offers.offer_category_id = 2 
      AND status.status_code IN(1, 2) 
      AND ( CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(offer_datePosted) = 4 AND HOUR(offer_datePosted) < 17 THEN 72*60*60 
                 WHEN WEEKDAY(offer_datePosted) = 4 AND HOUR(offer_datePosted) >= 17 THEN 9*60*60 + 96*60*60 
                 WHEN WEEKDAY(offer_datePosted) = 5 THEN 9*60*60+72*60*60 
                 WHEN WEEKDAY(offer_datePosted) = 6 THEN 9*60*60+48*60*60 ELSE 24*60*60 
            END ) < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(IF((WEEKDAY(offers.offer_datePosted) >= 4 
      AND HOUR(offer_datePosted) >= 17), CAST(offers.offer_datePosted as date), offers.offer_datePosted)))
```

Quick def: I hold a offer table where I store posts, status table to store flow of a post and cronjob to store which moderators or admin are warned if they are late to process this post. 
I want to do it with mysql instead of php code. I am wondering if it is a good sql approach? Code seems work but is it a good way to do that? Thanks for answering. If codes are written in sql and php properly, which one would be faster?

Comment: "Code seems work but is it a good way"...there is a separate CodeReview stackexchange site if you want to ask that kind of question. (But you'd have to check if your question is definitely on-topic there, before posting, and to be answerable it would need to contain a lot more information about the underlying schema, and a comprehensive data sample covering all test cases, before anyone could reasonably suggest changes. Also you need to define "good" - do you mean short code, or efficient performance, or something else?).

Comment: On this site we deal more with actual problems with code or technical questions about how to achieve a particular requirement. You've already achieved your requirement, you're just musing aloud about whether you like your code or not, as far as I can see. We don't really do that kind of question, it's too vague. And we can't tell you what would be faster because a) we can't see your PHP, b) we have no way of running the code. Performance is the result of more than just the pure code. If you want to test the performance, you can go ahead and test the performance yourself.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your answer.